# CSS3 Media Queries not working in Notepad++

Tags: html, css, media-queries, notepad++

I am adding the below `media query` directly to a style sheet to my webpage:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

background-color:red;

 }
```

So I am making the background colour change to red if the media type is screen and its maximum width is 480px. However Notepad++ is not picking up the media query as a CSS feature, it doesn't show in the colours as its supposed to.

[image: Screenshot of CSS media query]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe Notepad++ doesn't know that new CSS features?

Comment: What are you changing the background color of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #content {
        background-color:red;
    }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

see the first example, rules go inside of the media query

Comment: Oh what a douche I feel like... I was missing the ID selector

Answer (score 1):

your media screen don't have class or id.

you should Add class or id.

Ecxample:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    your class or id name{
        background-color:red;
    }
}
```

..............................................
.....................

class:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        .content{
            background-color:red;
        }
    }
```

..........

id:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
           #content{
                background-color:red;
            }
    }
```

Comment: you are right, he don't add the ID selector inside "{}"