# Media Query CSS and Notepad++ Compatibility Issue?

Tags: css, notepad++

I am using Notepad++ with my CSS for HTML. I type in

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {}
```

and in notepad++ it is not color coded like it is on here, which I find kind of worrying.
If you need a picture to see what I mean, here you go: [image]

The classes are color coded, but @media is not. Is this some incompatibility with NP++? or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Apparently NP++ doesn't recognize it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21686484/css3-media-queries-not-working-in-notepad (note the highlighting, not the incorrect CSS rule inside)

Comment: Alright, well I guess I'll trudge on and hope for the best xD Thanks

Comment: No problem.  If you don't mind a dark background and you want highlighting for that, I'd suggest Sublime Text or Atom.

Comment: What's particularly strange is that it seems to color `@import`, `@charset`, `@-webkit-keyframes` or even `@somenonexistentatkeyword` just fine. It's only `@media` where it fails to do so. Nothing in the langs.xml file suggests anything.

Comment: I recommend switching to Sublime as your editor. It does a far better job of coloring the code and has some awesome plugins. Once you switch, you won't go back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code is not incorrect. It's just that Notepad++ doesn't recognize media queries. But, that doesn't mean your code won't work on browsers/devices.

Don't worry about the color highlighting. You are doing it right.

Cheers!!!!

Comment: Thanks, I have been hevily relying on color coding to make sure I have things spelled correctly, and that things I'm using are correct.

Comment: @John Olivas: Looks like color coding will only get you so far then - see my comment above. Unfortunately I haven't met an editor whose CSS highlighting *isn't* buggy or incomplete in one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

Its just color highlighting , dont worry . But if this is uncomfotable , you can find patch / plugin which color for you media queries , Or simply switch yourself to PhpStorm or Sublime Text, its helping alot in coding if you using good IDE