# Media query not recognised in Notepad++

Tags: html, css, notepad++

I'm trying to use a media query in my CSS, however I'm unable to get the query to work.

It seems as though my CSS file doesn't recognise the term '@media' as a special term (i.e. it isn't highlighting itself blue like I would expect in notepad++.

Just wondering if anyone has experienced a similar issue before / what could be potentially causing this.

HTML in head tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

CSS

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      body {
        background-color: lightblue;
      }
    }
```

Comment: It appears to be working in my snippet. Can you provide some more information?

Comment: So, the problem is that it is not recognized by Notepad++, right? If you actually run the CSS in a browser that supports media queries, it works?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Media Query CSS and Notepad++ Compatibility Issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900101/media-query-css-and-notepad-compatibility-issue)

Comment: thanks guys, initially i thought the query wasn't actually working, but turns out it was but another div was hiding it. Looks like its just a compatibility issue but still functions fine in the browser.